# Python 3 changing log level dynamically seems not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

in my application I have a main class where I set this logging level configuration

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my-app')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING))
```

and other configuration to log on file. The others application objects uses this local logger

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger('{}.{}'.format('my-app', self.__class__.__name__))
```

and they can correctly log.
On runtime the application log level can changes, so I try to use this code in the other objects

```
level = logging.DEBUG
...
self.logger.setLevel(level)
- or -
logging.getLogger('my-app.'+self.__class__.__name__).setLevel(level)
- or -
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(level)
```

but none works.

So I decided to print the status of the logger object and I notice that the log level changes but no log line is printed on level lower than WARN

```
pprint(vars(self.logger), indent=2)
#prints
# on app starts, log level WARN by default
{ 'disabled': False,
'filters': [],
'handlers': [],
'level': 0,
'manager': <logging.Manager object at 0x7f5355eb1160>,
'name': 'ClientDesktop.CApplicationStatus',
'parent': <logging.Logger object at 0x7f5359743668>,
'propagate': True}
# on log changed to DEBUG
{ 'disabled': False,
'filters': [],
'handlers': [],
'level': 10,
'manager': <logging.Manager object at 0x7f5355eb1160>,
'name': 'ClientDesktop.CApplicationStatus',
'parent': <logging.Logger object at 0x7f5359743668>,
'propagate': True}
```

As you can see level changes but no log on file. I also debugged in to the logging library and I saw the check for loggin is verified, Since I don't change file path parameters I expect that should continue to works.

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**
As explained in bruno desthuilliers's response my handler has a parent

```
logging.getLogger('my-app')
```

where all the handlers are defined. Settings the parent level and all the handlers level to the new value does the trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.logger` has no handler(s), so it actually only delegates ("propagate") to it's parent(s). If all parents levels are above `DEBUG`, then the message will be discarded indeed.

Also, handlers have a level too, so even if a logger's level is set to `DEBUG`, the handler(s) will still filter message based on their own level. This allow to have different handlers for different levels for a same logger, but can also result in messages being discarded.

You did not provide enough informations (here your whole logging config) to positively tell this is the cause of your problem, but given the problem's description it's the most obvious culprit.

Comment: You are right: my `self.logger` has a parent (in the example is `logging.getLogger('my-app')`) and no handlers. All the handlers are defined in the parent. Setting the parent level and all the parent's handlers level does the trick